# TCP Proxy error on linux

Tags: c#, linux, proxy, mono

I'm trying to run an inner proxy on a Linux server, it's coded in C# and I'm using Mono to run it.
It works perfectly fine on Windows 7 however when I try to run it on Linux it throws an exception;

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at WorldSvrListener.Server.ListenForClients () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at WorldSvrListener.Server.ListenForClients () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I haven't written this class fully, most of it is from google, I studied it mostly and edited it but I still am not experienced enough with Classes and Objects.

Here's the code;

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace SvrListener
{
    class Server
    {
        static void Main()
        { 
            Server server = new Server();
            server.tcpListener.Start();
        }
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;

        public Server()
        {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 32666);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }
        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try and listen to:" + tcpListener.Server.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
                this.tcpListener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
            }
            catch (SocketException e) { Console.WriteLine("Error:" +e.ErrorCode + " "+ e.Message); }
            while (true)
            {
                //blocks until a client has connected to the server
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                //create a thread to handle communication 
                //with connected client
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
        private void HandleClientComm(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while (true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    //blocks until a client sends a message
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //a socket error has occured
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    //the client has disconnected from the server
                    break;
                }

                //message has successfully been received
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string s = message.Length.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));


                Thread forwardThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(forwardPacket));
                forwardThread.Start(message);
            }

            tcpClient.Close();
         }
        private void forwardPacket(object message)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            byte[] buffer = (byte[])message;
            IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.50"), 24585);

            client.Connect(serverEndPoint);

            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string shit = encoder.GetString(buffer);
            byte[] nBuffer = encoder.GetBytes(shit);

            clientStream.Write(nBuffer, 0, nBuffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
     }
}
}
```

UPDATE: So I tried the --debug command, it didn't give me anything useful;

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at WorldSvrListener.Server.ListenForClients () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00016] in /usr/src/mono-3.0.7/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Thread.cs:734
```

Comment: Is that the entire output? Did any of the `Console.WriteLine`s show up before that? Have you tried compiling and/or running this in debug mode to get a line number on that error?

Comment: Yes, that is the entire thing. No, nothing showed up at all. I don't have access to the debugger at the moment unfortunately.
Although I believe it has to be somewhere at the start since the first     Console.WriteLine did not show.

Comment: I posted a best guess, but if it isn't correct, please compile with debug information. You don't need an entire debugger for this, just use the `-debug` option when compiling and hopefully your stack trace should show line numbers.

Comment: I added some more information, I hope it helps a little...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, you are calling twice to Start(), in Main() and in ListenForClients(), try to remove the one at Main().

I had used mono in linux to create some servers and I must tell I had lots of troubles with TcpListener (but it was at least four years ago...), so finally went with a pure socket implementation which worked flawlessly.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed this.

Comment: This is offtopic, but both of your answers were correct, how do I accept both?

Comment: you can't, accept the one which solved your problem, if you had to change both... make an rnd.Next() and use it XD

Comment: Well, thank you both anyway :) I learned one more thing today.

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on the information available would be that it's dying on this line, as nothing else is printed:

```
Console.WriteLine("Try and listen to:" + tcpListener.Server.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
```

The documentation on MSDN doesn't really say when or if `Socket.LocalEndPoint` can return `null` but I think it would make sense for it to return `null` for unbound sockets. It might also be the case that on Mono's implementation, the socket isn't bound until `TcpListener.Start` is called.

Try moving that line after the `Start()` call and see if it makes things be not null.